# Install4j - creating a startup folder item

Tags: install4j

I have a multi-platform app and install4j creates installers for both Windows and macOS. One of the programs I'm deploying I would like added to the startup folder for Windows ONLY - not MacOS.

Is there a condition expression that I can put in the screen below which will allow the installer to determine if it's running on Windows and only add the launcher to automatically start for that OS and not macOS?

[image: Condition Expression]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition expression you are looking for is

```
Util.isWindows()
```